# How to make APT entirely skip package configuration

Tags: apt, debconf

I need apt to behave a like it does in multistrap, so I want it to only download and unpack packages on install, not configure them. This is done in an alternative rootdir.

I set the following option : `DPkg::ConfigurePending "false";`

But i still see debconf errors :

```
debconf: DbDriver "passwords" warning: could not open /var/cache/debconf/passwords.dat: Permission denied
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": could not write /var/cache/debconf/config.dat-new: Permission denied
Could not exec dpkg!
E:Sub-process /tmp/tmpcs0duzle/usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (100)
```

It is apparently still trying to call debconf in the host environment which can't work. How can I make APT skip the config step entirely ?